# Add custom field to order in magento

Tags: magento, custom-fields

I am new to Magento, All I need is add a custom field to order in back-end, and print that value on the PDF.

I want a save a sales person name with order when orders are added from back-end, and print the sales person name on PDF.

Any Idea? any better module or anything ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to add `mageigniter_sales_person` to your order db and add a input field to your admin create order and display it on order detail view

In /app/code/local/MageIgniter/CustomOrderSalesPerson/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageIgniter_CustomOrderSalesPerson>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </MageIgniter_CustomOrderSalesPerson>
    </modules>

    <global> 
         <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>                           
                <mageigniter_sales_person><to_order>*</to_order></mageigniter_sales_person>
            </sales_convert_quote>

            <sales_convert_order>                                              
                <mageigniter_sales_person><to_quote>*</to_quote></mageigniter_sales_person>
            </sales_convert_order>
        </fieldsets>
        <helpers>
            <customordersalesperson>
                <class>MageIgniter_CustomOrderSalesPerson_Helper</class>
            </customordersalesperson>            
        </helpers>

        <models>
            <customordersalesperson>
                <class>MageIgniter_CustomOrderSalesPerson_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>customordersalesperson_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </customordersalesperson>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <customordersalesperson_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>MageIgniter_CustomOrderSalesPerson</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </customordersalesperson_setup>
            <customordersalesperson_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </customordersalesperson_write>
            <customordersalesperson_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </customordersalesperson_read>
        </resources>

        <events>
            <adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before>
                <observers>
                    <customordersalesperson>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customordersalesperson/observer</class>
                        <method>saveCustomData</method>
                    </customordersalesperson>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data_before>
        </events>

        <blocks>
            <customordersalesperson>
                <class>MageIgniter_CustomOrderSalesPerson_Block</class>
            </customordersalesperson>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

In /app/code/local/MageIgniter/CustomOrderSalesPerson/sql/customordersalesperson_setup/mysql4-install-1.1.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("order", "mageigniter_sales_person", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "mageigniter_sales_person", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->endSetup();
```

In /app/code/local/MageIgniter/CustomOrderSalesPerson/Model/Observer.php

```
class MageIgniter_CustomOrderSalesPerson_Model_Observer 
{
    public function saveCustomData($event)
    {
        $quote = $event->getSession()->getQuote();
        $quote->setData('mageigniter_sales_person', $event->getRequestModel()->getPost('mageigniter_sales_person'));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

(You should avoid make changes to core default - you should do some research on way around this)

In /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/form/account.phtml

```
<input id="mageigniter_sales_person" name="mageigniter_sales_person" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote()->getMageigniterSalesPerson() ?>" class="input-text" type="text">
```

In /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml

```
<?php if($_order->getMageigniterSalesPerson()): ?>
<tr>
    <td class="label"><label><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sales Person') ?></label></td>
    <td class="value"><strong><?php echo $_order->getMageigniterSalesPerson() ?></strong></td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can get the current admin name using
     $_user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
     $user['email'] = $_user->getUser()->getEmail();
     $user['firstname'] = $_user->getUser()->getFirstname();
     $user['lastname'] = $_user->getUser()->getLastname();

In your pdf you should be able to access $_order->getMageigniterSalesPerson(), take a look @ [Add custom attribute to Magento’s PDF invoice](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-custom-attribute-to-magentos-pdf-invoice/)